# What is a representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let G be a compact Lie group with a maximal torus T, then what does the complex representation of G $\alpha:G\rightarrow U(n)$ mean? Does it mean that regarding 
$\alpha(g)$ as an isometry on $C^n$ for $g\in G$?

Also, it will be good someone let me know the representations $\alpha:G\rightarrow U(n)$ for $G=G_2,F_4,E_6,E_7,E_8$? I don't have J.F.Adams's book "Lectures on exceptional lie groups"at hand.

Comment: First question: it is a smooth homomorphism.  Second question: no, the condition you wrote only specifies a set-theoretic homomorphism; you need an additional differentiability condition that relates the isometries corresponding to nearby elements.

Comment: Closed. Please check the FAQ for more details. As usual if the answer is already on wikipedia, the question is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_representation for the representation theory. You can follow the links from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group#Exceptional_cases to find external links to the dimension sequences for the irreducible representations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Atlas of Lie groups](http://www.liegroups.org) software to compute representations.